# Is the Sage Advice Compendium considered a 1st-party resource?

Tags: dnd-5e, online-resources, wizards-of-the-coast, sage-advice

Is Jeremy Crawford's [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) considered official Wizards of the Coast content, or rather is it more his own home-rules?

Comment: Related: [Why do Crawford's tweets seem to be treated on par with the actual rules?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97294/why-do-crawfords-tweets-seem-to-be-treated-on-par-with-the-actual-rules), [Where do I find the “official” rules for D&D 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84836/where-do-i-find-the-official-rules-for-dd-5e), [With the 2019 Sage Advice Compendium release, are Jeremy Crawford's tweets considered to be "official rulings"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140221/33569)

Comment: To be clear, 1st party is the people making the game, 2nd party is the people playing the game, and 3rd party are people outside of that relationship offering content...  2nd party is *your own homebrew*.  You may want to clarify what you mean using a less confusing term.  ;)

Comment: I voted to close as unclear: When you say "used as official... content", what purpose are you thinking of "using" this for? Do you mean for discussion on this site? In your own game? Some other context? "Do I have to treat Sage Advice as gospel in internet discussions" is a very different question from "Do I have to use everything from Sage Advice in my game?"

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As the ["Official Rulings"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#OfficialRulings) section at the start of the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2021/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) states:

> Official rulings on how to interpret rules are made here in the *Sage Advice Compendium*. The public statements of the D&D team, or anyone else at Wizards of the Coast, are not official rulings; they are advice. The tweets of Jeremy Crawford (@JeremyECrawford), the game’s principal rules designer, are sometimes a preview of rulings that will appear here.

(Originally, Crawford's tweets were sometimes considered official rulings – though tweets by other designers never were. However, [as of 2019, only the rulings that appear in the Sage Advice Compendium are "official rulings"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140221/33569).)

Other pages on the [Wizards of the Coast website](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice) also refer to Sage Advice as "official rules answers" or "official clarifications of D&D rules". It's definitely an official, first-party source.

Note that rulings are interpretations of the rules. Sometimes, the rulings in the SAC merely restate what's already stated unambiguously in the rules; other times, these official rulings go beyond the rules as written and provide insight into the intent behind a rule. However, rulings are not the same as the actual rules of the game. Only those rules that appear in the D&D 5e books published by Wizards of the Coast are actually considered official *rules* for D&D 5e.

And regardless of what's "official", any individual group can play however they want. The official rules provide a shared starting point on how to play the game, but DMs can interpret or modify or ignore rules as they see fit. Jeremy Crawford frequently encourages those who dislike or disagree with certain rules or rulings to "follow their bliss" and play how they want to play.

Comment: It might also be worth tackling the misconception about what [1st, 2nd, and 3rd party mean](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/third_party); in this question, the 2nd party is rpgstar.

Comment: @V2Blast -- do you still remember what other pages pointed to the Sage Advice column and said it contains official rulings? It would be helpful for resolving [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/208654/75095)

Comment: @V2Blast, I just realized (from your description & lack of Diamond) it looks like you were one of the community managers affected by the most recent round of layoffs. I am really sorry for that - you were great and your helpful edits were likewise. I hope you find something else soon.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin: I was, yes. Thanks for the support.