# Are all magical staves and wands spellcasting foci?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting-focus

Are magical items such as:

> Staff of Frost DMG page 202
>
> Staff of Power DMG page 202
>
> Wand of Fireballs DMG page 210
>
> Wand of the War Mage +1 DMG page 212

Considered to be foci usable for spellcasting, such as:

> Staff PHB, page 151
>
> Wand PHB, page 151

Answer (score -1):

### No

A spellcasting focus is an object created to **be** a spellcasting focus. A magic staff or wand isn’t one unless it says it is just as a mundane quarter staff or wand shaped stick isn’t one.

Comment: Note: https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/02/09/can-wand-of-the-war-mage-be-an-arcane-focus/

Comment: Also note that Jeremy Crawford's rulings are considered "official"

Comment: so, is a yes or a no?

Comment: @L0neGamer worth noting that "official" in this case doesn't really mean anything much to us. See [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/137255/28591) for more. Crawford writes rulings not rules and his rulings are completely optional.

Comment: @foffos basically it's a "your DM has to decide".  J.C. says yes, but your DM can rule differently and it's not "wrong".